# SQL query error 'missing right parenthesis'

Tags: sql, oracle

when running the following below SQL query I get the message:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 32 Column: 18
```

I recently added dv6.long_name toll_system_type to the query so I know it has something to do with that, as it was working fine before.

Here is the SQL:

```
with t as (SELECT  DISTINCT dv6.long_name toll_system_type,  
  ti.tollsystem_id, 
  ti.toll_id,  
  pp.type,  
  dv.published_value,  
  nvl(dv.long_name, 'N/A') paypoint_type,  
  pp.map_id,  
  pp.map_id_entry,   
  nvl(dv2.long_name, 'N/A') tollpaymentmethod,  
  c.currency, 
  c.accuracy, 


  c.per_distance, 
  nvl(dv3.long_name, 'N/A') currencytype ,  
  COUNT (DISTINCT ti.toll_id) count_Toll_ID, 
  (COUNT (DISTINCT c.cost_id)) count_costid, 
  MIN(asr.subregion) AS region 
FROM  
  WEU_bw_.TC_TOLL_ID ti,   
  WEU_bw_.TC_PAYPOINT pp,  
  WEU_bw_.nt_domain_value dv,  
  WEU_bw_.tc_cost_paymethod cp,  
  WEU_bw_.nt_domain_value dv2,   
  WEU_bw_.tc_cost c,  
  WEU_bw_.nt_domain_value dv3, 
  WEU_bw_.nt_condition con, 
  WEU_bw_.nt_nav_strand ns, 
  WEU_bw_.nt_nav_link nl, 
  WEU_bw_.nt_link l, 
  WEU_bw_.qt_admin_subregions asr
  WEU_bw_.nt_domain_value dv6, 
WHERE ti.toll_id           = pp.toll_id 
AND pp.map_id              = con.multi_nav_pvid(+) 
AND con.strand_id          = ns.nav_strand_id(+) 
AND ns.nav_link_id         = nl.nav_link_id(+) 
AND nl.link_id             = l.link_id(+) 
AND l.left_admin_place_id  = asr.admin_place_id(+)  
AND ti.toll_id             = c.toll_id 
AND c.cost_id              = cp.cost_id (+) 

AND dv.domain_id           = 1999567214  
AND dv.value(+)            = pp.type 

AND dv2.domain_id(+)       = 1994328351  
AND dv2.value(+)           = cp.type 

AND dv3.domain_id          = 1994571604  
AND dv3.value(+)           = c.currency

AND dv6.domain_id(+)       = 1995788373
AND dv6.value(+)           = ti.tollsystem_id


GROUP BY ti.tollsystem_id,
  ti.tollsystem_id,  
  ti.toll_id,  
  pp.type,  
  dv.published_value,  
  dv.long_name,  
  pp.map_id, 
  pp.map_id_entry,  
  dv2.long_name,  
  c.currency,  
  dv3.long_name, 
  c.accuracy,  
  c.per_distance 
ORDER BY 1) 


SELECT DISTINCT
  t.tollsystem_id, 
  t.toll_id,  
  t.type,  
  t.published_value,  
  t.paypoint_type,  
  t.map_id,  
  t.map_id_entry,   
  t.currency, 


  t.per_distance, 
  t.currencytype ,  
  t.count_Toll_ID, 


  t.region 
FROM t
```

Comment: Have you counted the `(` and `)`? Same number?

Comment: Value is a reserved word, at least in ANSI SQL, needs to be delimited as `"value"`.

Comment: Does Oracle allow ORDER BY in the sub-query like that?

Answer (score 5):

You have an extra comma and a missing comma:

```
FROM  
  WEU_bw_.TC_TOLL_ID ti,   
  WEU_bw_.TC_PAYPOINT pp,  
  WEU_bw_.nt_domain_value dv,  
  WEU_bw_.tc_cost_paymethod cp,  
  WEU_bw_.nt_domain_value dv2,   
  WEU_bw_.tc_cost c,  
  WEU_bw_.nt_domain_value dv3, 
  WEU_bw_.nt_condition con, 
  WEU_bw_.nt_nav_strand ns, 
  WEU_bw_.nt_nav_link nl, 
  WEU_bw_.nt_link l, 
  WEU_bw_.qt_admin_subregions asr    --Add the comma here
  WEU_bw_.nt_domain_value dv6,       --Remove the comma from here
```

Comment: Extra and missing is a rare combination.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. It fixed the issue but I am not sure what to use as the final select distinct, I have: 
SELECT DISTINCT
  t.long_name toll_system_type
  t.toll_system_type
  t.tollsystem_id, 
  t.toll_id,  
  t.type,  
  t.published_value,  
  t.paypoint_type,  
  t.map_id,  
  t.map_id_entry,   
  t.currency,
  
  

  t.per_distance, 
  t.currencytype ,  
  t.count_Toll_ID, 
  

  t.region 
FROM t

Comment: @DanBracuk, not that odd, OP did probably switch the selected column order and forgot to move the comma. (Been there, done that...)